# Setup run configurations for every script for project in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, aptana, pydev

I work in eclipse+pydev. In my projects I have approximately 100-200 files and every script can be execute. Eclipse can setup run configuration for every one by one. But I'd like to setup one run configuration for project and I'd like to use this configuration for every script for launch. I needed this because I have custom parameters for launch (but this parameters the same for every script).

Comment: Is the script file passed in as an argument to your launch configuration?

Comment: If I use Ctrl+F11 I run my script. I 'd like to setup several parameter for VM (python). Eclipse (Aptana) can do this. But I can do it just for one script, not for every one.

Answer (score 0):

Right now that's not possible in PyDev, and I'm not sure it'd be so useful -- if there's some parameter you have to pass to 200 scripts, the usual way to have that configuration would not be as command line arguments, but usually through an environment variables or some configuration file (whose default location would be something as ~/.my_app in Linux or using %APPDATA%/MyApp in windows).

If you have a use-case that differs from that for some reason, please create a feature request in PyDev (see: http://pydev.org/about.html for links) explaining your use-case.

If you decide to go through the environment variables way, you can set it up in the shell where you start Eclipse (but before starting Eclipse and you must restart Eclipse if you change it) or in the interpreter configuration (window > preferences > pydev > interpreter - Python > environment).